# SSRS Expression adding Time together

Tags: reporting-services, time, expression

What's the best way to add times together?

My time is in the format of 
        00:00:00

I'm looking to add these up in an expression in SSRS.

Comment: Can you share a sample data and the output you want?

Comment: TalkTime
05:22:02       
NotReadyTime
00:09:46        
WrapTime
00:13:33      
WaitTime
02:27:55

Comment: I want to be able in an expression to get the total time.

Comment: you want to get the sum of it?

Comment: yes but I keep having errors or the sum is about 5 hours out

Comment: you can check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699490/ssrs-total-for-time

Comment: Tried this and the time was out by 5 hours

Comment: This depends on the data type of the data, is it a string or a date/time datatype? Also when you say "add", do you want to add values across different cells in a row ( a+b+c ) or a column ( sum(a) ) ?